# Bootstrap 4 Grid "order-3" Among Multiple Unordered Elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to place an element in the 3rd position of a Bootstrap 4 Grid among several unordered elements.

To my knowledge, only "order-first" and "order-last" are able to override the position of unordered elements in the Bootstrap Grid. If all other elements are unordered, "order-3" places the element last.

Am I missing something, or does anyone know of a potential workaround?

Comment: I think you have to set the order position of the preceeding elements first.

Comment: So you would have to use order 1 and order 2 on the previous elements

Comment: The grid is created through a loop using Razor syntax - so what you're suggesting is potentially possible to do by assigning the loop iteration to the order number.